# How do I enforce "single source of truth" in pure FP?

Tags: functional-programming

In a OO system, I could have a "Data" object, and share a reference with several other objects. If I update the data object, any object with a reference will see the updated data.

In pure FP system, we have an issue where for any data structure we can ask "Should it store such and such data, or should we expect that data to be passed in?"

E.g. I have to decide, If it's ok to have something like:

`students : Dict StudentId Student
toString : Dict StudentId Student -> StudentId -> Maybe String`

  or is it better to have

`studentIds : Set StudentId
toString : (StudentId -> Maybe Student) -> StudentId -> Maybe String`

The former runs the risk of duplicating the relationship or data, or having differing truths.

Comment: I don't get where you would have duplication or "differing truths", but I would expect a `toString` function to have the type `Student -> String` and then `fmap` that over the `Maybe Student` which is the result of a `StudentId` lookup.

Comment: @Bergi in the first example, think of `Dict StudentId Student` as a database. In the second example, think of `(StudentId -> Maybe Student)` as a connection to a database. If coding with the first style, you run the risk of having several out of sync DBs if you aren't careful. You don't run that risk with the second example.

Comment: You still do. You haven't shown how the "database" might be mutated, but the second style is just as error-prone as the first. `(StudentId -> Maybe Student)` is a pure function, it's not stateful, so you need to keep multiple "connections" in "sync" now, always calling `toString` with the "current" connection.

Comment: You're proving my point. If I must always call `toString` with a connection parameter, then it's not my responsibility to keep state in sync. I've pushed the responsibility to the caller. Not so with a Dict.

Comment: The two types you provided are equivalent for your purpose. Whether it is the responsibility of the caller to provide the "current" dictionary or to provide the "current" connection does not make a difference.

Comment: They aren't equivalent because if the caller always passes in the mapping function, the callee can not be out of sync with the parent. Not so if the callee has it's own copy of the data. So in a perfect world, they are equivalent. In the real world, we can make a mistake with the first which is impossible with the second.

Comment: There can exist multiple mapping functions (some of them out of date) just as there can exist multiple dictionaries. Whatever you are passing, it is not mutable, and the callee always gets "a copy".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179136/discussion-between-z5h-and-bergi).